# How to change the titlebar in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to change the `titlebar` color of my `pygame` window. Because I need to have the background white, but the titlebar is also white. Everyone says to just hide the `titlebar`.

That's not possible because

1. I need to be able to close the program with the x button,
2. I want to be able to move the window,
3. I want to see the tite and the logo,
4. Its just much prettier.

Comment: You cannot change the color of the title bar in pygame. The color is determined by the operating system.

Comment: `titlebar` is created by system (Windows, Mac, Linux) and `pygame` can't change it. You may eventually hide `titlebar` and create something similar inside `pygame` screen. But it would need to write all code which displays and process closing button, code which moves window, etc. Some people do something like this but in `tkinter`

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to add some border/line at the top of you background - and then you will see where is background and where is titlebar.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the titlebar a pygame window; that area is beyond the control of pygame. As you already know, you can hide it and draw your own, but then you lose the quit button and the drag functionality and would have to implement them yourself. And yes, both functionalities are possible to implement if you really want to.